# Data processing on multiple servers - Azure

Tags: parsing, azure, architecture, rss, restful-architecture

We have WebApi cloud service which is receiving list of feed urls as parameter, and returning parsed HTML files of actual articles from these feeds... So processing logic is something like this:

- Download all feeds
- Parse all articles from feeds
- Get all actual articles links
- Download all articles html
- Parse all article html
- Return results

Doing parallel processing on one machine (4 cores) works pretty fine with 1 or 2 feeds with small number of articles. But we need architecture which can process 20 - 30 feeds and 300 - 500 articles in parallel.

[image]

This is our current idea. Host two cloud service (Feed parsing and Article parsing).

Feed parsing service is exposed to users which are sending list of feeds as parameters to this service. This service is splinting this list into smaller chunks and sending them for processing on Article parsing service.

Article parsing service will have a few vm instance under one cloud service, and Azure will by default every request process on different instance (load-balancing done)

So result should be that all articles are processed in parallel.

But I think that there is smarter way to accomplish this on Azure, any other idea guys?

Also background pre-processing is not an option.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are some other requirements not stated (i.e responsiveness for users submitting requests and overall time to process). However, making some assumptions (asynchronous response at some later time) I could hazard a guess. My first thought is that you don't need 2 cloud services. You could have 1 that takes user requests and places the units of work onto an azure queue. You could then have N workers that wait on the queue and take the next available item. When they are finished they could store the results in persistent storage (SQL Azure, Table/Blob storage) and put a completion notice on another queue. More speculation here, but unless you have already profiled a sample set of this work you may not be correct about where most of the time is spent. In other words it may not be necessary to break the work into 2 stages (extract links, then parse articles) and it may be fast enough to just have a unit of work encompass both steps. I always try the simpler solution first, and then if I need more performance I refactor for it. If, however, that does not meet your requirements for processing time and you want more parallelization then you could still use the basic approach I outlined, but with 2 queues, 1 for each stage. It might even be the same worker process waiting on both queues just in different threads, or it could be totally separate processes. Other design constraints might dictate (i.e. costs, total throughput).

Comment: Your solution with queues and workers is more elegant than the one I describe.  That was our initial idea also. Reasons why we drop it off are costs and additional complexity which is coming with queues and workers, but most important is costs of running on-demand workers and queues.

Comment: It would not necessarily be more expensive in terms of raw azure costs to use this approach. That would depend on how many VMs are needed in each scenario and so on. Storage costs for the queues are not likely to be significant, though that would depend on volume. The use of queues themselves is not terribly complex, though I suppose you could argue slightly more complex than a load balanced HTTP request.